# Referencing a java object using a string in a foreach loop

Tags: java

Is there some way I can reference an object using the actual "value" from the string in a for loop?

I'll try to explain (I am very new to java!):

```
for(String provider:response.gO.providers)

{ System.out.println(response.gO.identities.{provider}.nickName); 

}
```

Here I would want each value of provider in the list to replace {provider} so it prints the value of each nickname.

Basically I have a giant list of providers and the only way I currently know how to do this is using lots of if statements for each value of provider as so:

> for(String provider:response.gO.providers){
>
> ```
>  if ("providerx".equalsIgnoreCase(provider))
>      System.out.println(response.gO.identities.providerx.nickName);
>
>  if ("providery".equalsIgnoreCase(provider))
>      System.out.println(response.gO.identities.providery.nickName);   }
> ```

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a `HashMap` instead.

Comment: You will need to write a getter at the very least that takes a String and returns the correct provider. As above, HashMap allows you to use the provider name as a key and the stored item as the Provider object.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, in general you cannot do this in Java.
The Java syntax does not allow it.

In Java, in this element
`response.gO.identities.{provider}.nickName`
the `{provider}` part needs to be known at compile time.

What you want is to delay knowing it until runtime.
So that's not possible.

2) You can do this with Reflection though.

[Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)